# Recovery Mode Database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Today I was trying to attach the `.MDF, .NDF, .LDF` files for a SQL Server 2005 database which I have received from my client. After attachment the database status is showing (Read-Only) (Eg.database name (Read-Only).

How do I make this to normal mode for updating the data? Is there any query available to resolve this problem? Your help will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL Statement should make you able to do updates:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database name> SET READ_WRITE
```

If that doesn't work then I suspect there are some problems with permissions as the files come from a different server.